# OpenVPN Multiple Public Ips Config on CentOS 7

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, centos-7

I currently have a cloud node on an online host and with 3 public ips assigned to a CentOS 7 instance. Is there a way to run an OpenVPN server listening on all 3 IPs? I do not need the instances to be able to talk to each other but it would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing the web and contacting friends, I found a way to make a TCP-based OpenVPN system listen on multiple addresses. Here is a guide to setting up your OpenVPN server to make use of multiple public IPs.

1. Make sure your VPN config file does not have the local directive. This directive forces the server to only listen on one IP.
2. Configure your firewall to route external traffic IP to your OpenVPN subnet. I'm using CentOS and firewalld so the command is `firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o $SHARK -j MASQUERADE`
3. Configure the rest of your VPN as you normally would. By making sure routing works correctly, your VPN server can listen on any number of IPs.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't specify `--local` argument the OpenVPN is supposed to bind to all available interfaces.

If you need to constrain it to only the 3 IP addresses I would try to specify the `--local` parameter

- three times in row, `--local 200.0.0.1 --local 200.0.0.2 --local 200.0.0.3`
- or with range `--local 200.0.0.1-3`
- or maybe comma separated

It's a long shot though.